# xslt nested emphasis tags conversion

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am having an issue with some of my files, could use help solving it. I am converting from html to xml. sometimes I have a `<b>` or `<u>` or `<i>` tag on their own and I use

```
<xsl:template match="i">
<emphasis italic="yes">
<xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
</emphasis>
</xsl:template>
```

or bold for b and underline for u.

Sometimes I have a nested `<u>` in a `<b>`

for these I use

```
<xsl:template match="b/u">
<xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

this is to get rid of the `u`

```
<xsl:template match="b[u]">
<emphasis bold="yes" underline="yes">
<xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
</emphasis>
</xsl:template>
```

this is to convert the `b` followed by a `u`.

Now my issue is what to do when it a `u` nested in an `i` nested in a `b`. What is the code for this?

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your immediate question, to match an `u` nested in an `i` nested in a `b` you would do this

```
<xsl:template match="b/i/u">
```

You would also need templates to handle the parent `b` and `i`

```
<xsl:template match="b[i/u]">

<xsl:template match=b/i[u]">
```

But presumably you want to cope with elements nested in any order? And coding templates for each possible permuation is going to get very messy, and you would also have to worry about two templates matching the same element.

Instead, try this XSLT which is slightly more flexible, although not particularly elegant

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="i[parent::b|parent::u]" name="italic">
      <xsl:attribute name="italic">yes</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="b[parent::i|parent::u]" name="bold">
      <xsl:attribute name="bold">yes</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="u[parent::b|parent::i]" name="underline">
      <xsl:attribute name="underline">yes</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
   </xsl:template>   

   <xsl:template match="*[self::b|self::i|self::u][not(parent::b)][not(parent::i)][not(parent::u)]">
      <emphasis>
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="self::b">
            <xsl:call-template name="bold"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="self::i">
            <xsl:call-template name="italic"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="self::u">
            <xsl:call-template name="underline"/>
            </xsl:when>
         </xsl:choose>
      </emphasis>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The idea is that you have templates matching `i`, `b` or `u` elements that have other such elements as parents. In this case you just output the relevant attribute.

You also have the main template that matches the top most `i`, `b` or `u` element (i.e. one with no other such element as parent) where you output the **emphasis** element. Note the use of named templates simpler to avoid some code duplication.

When you apply it to the following XML

```
<test>
   <b>bold</b>
   <i>Italic</i>
   <b><i>bold Italic</i></b>
   <u><b><i>bold Italic underline</i></b></u>
</test>
```

The following is output

```
<test>
   <emphasis bold="yes">bold</emphasis>
   <emphasis italic="yes">Italic</emphasis>
   <emphasis bold="yes" italic="yes">bold Italic</emphasis>
   <emphasis underline="yes" bold="yes" italic="yes">bold Italic underline</emphasis>
</test>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a simple and short solution: only two templates, no explicit conditional instructions**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:names>
   <n short="b">bold</n>
   <n short="i">italic</n>
   <n short="u">underline</n>
 </my:names>

 <xsl:variable name="vNames" select="document('')/*/my:names/*"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "node()[not(contains('+b+i+u+', concat('+',name(),'+')))]
         /*[contains('+b+i+u+', concat('+',name(),'+'))]
  ">
   <emphasis>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="emph"/>
   </emphasis>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template mode="emph"
   match="*[contains('+b+i+u+', concat('+',name(),'+'))]">
   <xsl:attribute name="{$vNames[@short=name(current())]}">yes</xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="emph"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<test>
   <b>bold</b>
   <i>Italic</i>
   <b><i>bold Italic</i></b>
   <u><b><i>bold Italic underline</i></b></u>
</test>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<emphasis bold="yes">bold</emphasis>
<emphasis italic="yes">Italic</emphasis>
<emphasis bold="yes" italic="yes">bold Italic</emphasis>
<emphasis underline="yes" bold="yes" italic="yes">bold Italic underline</emphasis>
```